# Type Script to search multiple property in an Array object

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I am using Array.prototype.filter to search  first name from the Object name array. I would want to modify my search to search first name and if it is not there search the last name.

```
student_name : any = [{name:"Udhay" ,  lname:"Ravi"},
                {name:"Sabari" , lname:"Raj"},
                {name:"Sachin" , lname:"Karthi"},
                {name:"Sudha" ,  lname:"Mohan"}]

search(){
var this.myInput = "Ravi"
this.student_name = this.student_name.filter((sn) => {               
return(sn.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.myInput.toLowerCase())> -1)
 })

}
```

Can someone please help me on this. I am very new to TypeScript and Angular 2

Answer (score 1):

It would look like this:

```
search() {
    this.myInput = "Ravi";

    // Convert it to lower case here to avoid lower case conversion twice inside filter.
    let searchFilter = this.myInput.toLowerCase();

    this.student_name =
        this.student_name.filter(sn =>
            sn.name.toLowerCase() === searchFilter ||
            sn.lname.toLowerCase() === searchFilter);
}
```

`filter` function will perform the comparison on each element, that's why there's no need to use `indexOf`. It's like performing a `for` loop over each element in the initial array and pushing the elements that meet the condition inside a new array which will later be returned as a result of the `filter` function.

**EDIT:**

Check if any name or last name `starts with` the search string:

```
sn.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchFilter) ||
sn.lname.toLowerCase().startsWith(searchFilter)
```

Check if any name or last name `contains` the search string:

```
sn.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchFilter) ||
sn.lname.toLowerCase().includes(searchFilter)
```

Comment: Thank you msmolcic. Problem what I see with the solution is, it give the exact match and not the appropriate match. I want to implement the logic in search bar.

Comment: @Udhay In your example you were searching for the exact match, that's why I gave you this example. It's simple to change the filter condition if you want to check whether any name/last name `starts with` or `contains` the input string. Check the `edit` part of the answer and change the condition inside of the filter to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved easily using lodash

```
search(){
this.myInput = "Ravi"
this.result= _.filter(this.student_name, {'name':this.myInput});
if(_.isEmpty(this.result)){
  this.result=_.filter(this.student_name, {'lname':this.myInput})
 }
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/FS8aRmHc4Du7BDyApzQk?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

I have written a very simple to use library [ss-search](https://github.com/yann510/ss-search).

In your case, to search the nested array, you would do the following:

```
search(student_name, ["name", "lname"], "Ravi")
```

This will filter out the data to return only results containing "Ravi" in the name or last name property.